# Обращение из активности к элементам CardView в RecycleView, который реализован во фрагменте, после "пересоздания" (поворота экрана) активности

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, cardview, activity-life-cycle

В активности создаю объект View в котором сохраняю ссылку на RecyclerView, который реализован во фрагменте:

```
View parentView = findViewById(R.id.common_recycler);
```

Посредством созданного объекта я обращаюсь к элементам CardView реализованного для RecyclerView. Метод где реализован этот код вызывается в двух случаях. Первый - при обработке нажатии (касании экрана) пользователем объекта фрагмента - все отлично работает. Второй - когда я хочу обработать "пересоздания" активности. В этом случае я получаю ссылку на RecyclerView - но в нем не создан CardView и соответственно объекты которые он содержит.

Вызов метода я пробовал и в onRestoreInstanceState и onResum и onResume и onPostResum и onPostResume и onResumeFragment. Ссылку на RecyclerView получаю (но в логкате видно что он "пустой") а CardView и его элементы (соответственно) не созданы и при попытке получить ссылку по ид - результат null. Я так понимаю, что реализация этого метода во фрагменте смысла не имеет, так как переопределенный метод onResumeFragment и есть onResum в фрагменте. Получилось реализовать задуманное (сохранение состояния CardView) при вызове в методе onWindowFocusChanged, но это не очень красиво и не эффективно. Благодарю за любые соображения.

Comment: Судя по описанному вы делаете очень неправильные вещи. Обращаться из активити к View из ViewHolder RecyclerView фрагмента - неправильно. Активити ничего не должна знать о разметке фрагмента, а фрагмент ничего не должен знать о View из RecyclerView. Если вы опишите что именно вы хотите сделать - напишем как это делать правильно. На данный момент есть лишь догадки о том, что у вас как-то не так отображается список после поворота экрана.

Comment: Есть активити в котором есть фрагмент с RecyclerView (он в разметке фрагмента) для него реализован отдельный класс-адаптер RecycleView в нем описан CardView (ViewHolder). При нажатие на элемент, который размещен в макете CardView вызывается метод обработки (его можно реализовать только в активити, насколько я понимаю) при этом макет CardView меняет вид, который надо сохранить после поворота экрана.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я сомоучка, пишу свое приложение, если надо я прикреплю здесь файлы с кодом. Как я понимаю Вас все методы обработки макета CardView надо реализовывать в фрагменте (или в классе адаптера)? Я бы так и делал, но обработчик нажатия onClick, среда разработки говорит, что надо реализовывать только в активити, но может я не так понял.

Comment: onClick можно где угодно описать, можно и прямо во ViewHolder. Типа как-то так, если на [tag:kotlin]: `someView.setOnClickListener { /*ТУТ КОД*/ }`. Сохранять внешний вид - сложнее. Правильно будет так: 1. Данные, которые влияют на внешний вид должны быть в модели данных. 2. Модели данных должны хранится в экземпляре класса, который переживёт поворот экрана. В реальном мире это может быть Presenter в рамках архитектурного подхода MVP. 3. После изменения данных модели адаптеру об этом сообщается и он перерисовывается. (`notifyDataSetChanged()`)

Comment: После вашего замечания по поводу неправильности обращения к элементам View, я подумал, погуглил и есть соображение - реализовать интерфейс onClickListener в классе-адаптере (где и описывается CardView) и все последующие манипуляции с макетом проводить там же. Что даст возможность правильно реагировать на "возобновление" после поворота. Скажите, пожалуйста, в правильном ли направление мысль? Благодарю

Comment: Не обязательно именно в адаптере реализовывать. Можно и просто анонимный класс сделать. Если на [tag:java] то примерно так: `someView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(VIew view) { /*ТУТ КОД*/ } })`. Однако само по себе место обработки нажатия никак не поможет с восстановлением данных. Это совершенно отдельная задача и решается она очень по разному. Сложно что-то конкретное сказать по этому поводу кроме общих соображений, уже высказанных выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, ЮрийСПб, за задание правильного направления. Не знаю чисто ли с точки зрения оптимальности кода реализовано решение, но оно работает. ЮрийСПб, сказал что неправильно обращаться из активити к view CardHolderView и RecyclerView расположенных во фрагменте. Поэтому всю логику по обработке элементов CardView я реализовал в адаптере. А сохранение состояния CardView после поворота экрана (которое подразумевает сохранение двух параметров типа int), посредством статических переменных. Единственное пришлось в самом фрагменте в onPause реализовать "отсоединение" адаптера, чтобы в самом адаптере сохранить нужные параметры в событии onDetachedFromRecyclerView. С радостью приму замечания и комментарии к "методу" решения моего вопроса.